# Rails: if has_many relationship changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got these two classes.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :issue, :name, :page, :image, :video, :brand_ids
  has_many :publications
  has_many :docs, :through => :publications
end

class Doc < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :issue_id, :cover_id, :message, :article_ids, :user_id, :created_at, :updated_at, :issue_code, :title, :template_id
  has_many :publications, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :articles, :through => :publications, :order => 'publications.position'
  has_many :edits, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :articles, allow_destroy: false
end
```

How would I write a conditional statement to see if `@doc.articles` has changed after updating `@doc`?

```
if @doc.articles.changed?
  ...
end
```

The above gives me an error. I can't find the correct syntax.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to check each one. `.changed?` only works on a single record. You could do something like this if you need to check the whole association for at least one change:

```
if @doc.articles.find_index {|a| a.changed?} then...
```

Or you can use `Enumerable#any?`:

```
if @doc.articles.any? {|a| a.changed?} then...
```

Comment: What about the case where a has_many is added to the list?  This is a change, but will it be detected this way?

Comment: Is there a way to detect if @person.task_ids_changed?. I'd like to detect if the _ids array changes.

Comment: You can also write it as `@doc.articles.any?(&:changed?)`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the case where an associated object was added or removed.

Comment: @PawanAgarawal yes, that is true. The changed? method specifically indicates whether an existing attribute has changed value, or if a new one has been added but not yet saved to the database. The OP doesn't say whether they want to include the removal or addition of a article.

Comment: If you'd also like to account for when an associated object was added or removed, you could do `@doc.articles.any?(&:changed?) || @doc.articles.collect(&:id).sort != @doc.articles.pluck(&:id).sort`. This works because `collect` will pull the ids from the in-memory associations (including `nil` items in the array for not-yet saved associations, and excluding ids from the array for to-be-deleted associations), while `pluck` pulls the ids from the database (which does the opposite, excluding not-yet-saved association ids and including to-be-deleted association ids).

Comment: In `@doc.articles.pluck(&:id).sort` `pluck(&:id)` needs to be changed to `pluck(:id)`

Answer (score 19):

Use the `after_add` and `after_remove` association callbacks to check for additions/removals along with using `saved_changes?` to check for any changes on existing articles.

```
class Doc < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles, after_add: :set_article_flag, after_remove: :set_article_flag

  after_save :do_something_with_changed_articles

  private

  def set_article_flag
    @articles_changed = true
  end

  def do_something_with_changed_articles
    if @articles_changed || articles.any?(&:saved_changes?)
      # do something
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This points me in the right direction thx @akaspick

Comment: These methods are at the very end of the doc on callbacks, so I've missed it for years: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/association_basics.html#association-callbacks

Comment: @DavidKrider They're also in the API docs at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html and search for "Association Callbacks"

Comment: Oh my goodness - I never knew these existed. I have also missed them for years. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

A bit late, but for other people who are looking for a similar solution, you can detect changes in the Relationship (also has_and_belongs_to_many) on this way:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :issue, :name, :page, :image, :video, :brand_ids
  has_many :publications
  has_many :docs, :through => :publications
end

class Doc < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :issue_id, :cover_id, :message, :article_ids, :user_id, :created_at, :updated_at, :issue_code, :title, :template_id
  has_many :publications, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :articles, :through => :publications, :order => 'publications.position'
  has_many :edits, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :articles, allow_destroy: false

  after_initialize :initialize_article_changes_safe

  after_save :change_articles
  after_save :initialize_article_changes

  before_add_for_articles << ->(method,owner,change) { owner.send(:on_add_article, change) }
  before_remove_for_articles << ->(method,owner,change) { owner.send(:on_remove_article, change) }

  def articles_changed?
    @article_changes[:removed].present? or @article_changes[:added].present?
  end

  private

  def on_add_article(article)
    initialize_article_changes_safe
    @article_changes[:added] << article.id
  end

  def on_remove_article(article)
    initialize_article_changes_safe
    @article_changes[:removed] << article.id
  end

  def initialize_article_changes
    @article_changes = {added: [], removed: []}
  end

  def initialize_article_changes_safe
    @article_changes = {added: [], removed: []} if @article_changes.nil?
  end

  def unchanged_article_ids
    self.article_ids - @article_changes[:added] - @article_changes[:removed]
  end

  def change_articles
    do_stuff if self.articles_changed?
    do_stuff_for_added_articles unless @article_changes[:added].nil?
    do_stuff_for_removed_articles unless @article_changes[:removed].nil?
  end
end
```

The two hooks `before_add_for_NAME-OF-RELATION` and `before_remove_for_NAME-OF-RELATION` are triggered when adding or removing a relation. The triggered functions (you can not link a function by name, you have to do it by lambda) add the ids of the added / removed relation items to the `@articel_changes` hash. When the model is saved, you can handle the objects by their ids in the `change_articles` function. After it, the `@articel_changes` hash will be cleared.

Comment: This seems overly complicated considering in rails you have `before_add, after_add, before_remove, after_remove` callbacks you can define on the associations.

Comment: @dft this is right on normal relation but not on a has_and_belongs_to_many relation. The has_and_belongs_to_many relation table is without primary keys and only contains the two ids. So even if you get an trigger from the hooks, its very tricky to get the id from the target object during the change process.
An other solution is to create an intermediate table and also an intermediate model. but than you have a classic 1:n relation.

Comment: this was a life saver

Answer (score 3):

I found **Enumerable#any?** helpful with an intermediate step of reverse sorting by id in following manner:

```
@doc.articles.sort { |a, b| b.id <=> a.id }.any?(&:changed?)
```

That sort step helps **any?** to return early, instead of looping through older **article** records to find if any change was made.

For e.g. in my case I had a `has_many :event_responders` relation and after adding a new `EventResponder` to the collection, I validated the above to be working in following manner:

**Without using an intermediate sort**

```
2.2.1 :019 > ep.event_responders.any? { |a| puts a.changes; a.changed? }
{}
{}
{}
{}
{"created_at"=>[Thu, 03 Sep 2015 08:25:59 UTC +00:00, Thu, 03 Sep 2015 08:25:59 UTC +00:00], "updated_at"=>[Thu, 03 Sep 2015 08:25:59 UTC +00:00, Thu, 03 Sep 2015 08:25:59 UTC +00:00]}
=> true
```

**Using an intermediate sort**

```
2.2.1 :020 > ep.event_responders.sort { |a, b| b.id <=> a.id }.any? { |a| puts a.changes; a.changed? }
{"created_at"=>[Thu, 03 Sep 2015 08:25:59 UTC +00:00, Thu, 03 Sep 2015 08:25:59 UTC +00:00], "updated_at"=>[Thu, 03 Sep 2015 08:25:59 UTC +00:00, Thu, 03 Sep 2015 08:25:59 UTC +00:00]}
=> true
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Building up on [@jangosteve's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727130/rails-if-has-many-relationship-changed#comment74582620_16727194), you can create a magic method that responds to [association]_changed?, whatever the association name:

`app/models/application_record.rb`

```rb
def method_missing(method_name, *arguments, &block)
  if method_name.to_s =~ /(.*)_changed?/
    association = $1.to_sym
    send(association).any?(&:changed?) || send(association).collect(&:id).sort != send(association).pluck(:id).sort
  else
    super
  end
end

def respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private = false)
  if method_name.to_s =~ /(.*)_changed?/
    association = $1.to_sym
    self.class.reflect_on_association(association).present?
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build out a custom solution using `cache_key_with_version` and `after_commit`.

You will need to persist the `cache_key_with_version` to a column in the database. Then you can run certain code if the key changed. This is a decent amount of overhead so I would only recommend this if you have a fairly heavy task.

As an example

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
  
  after_commit :run_comment_analysis, :persist_cache_key

  def persist_cache_key
    self.tmp_comments_cache_key = comments.cache_key_with_version
    self.save!
  end

  def run_comment_analysis
    if comments.cache_key_with_version != tmp_comments_cache_key
      # RunJob Code
    end
  end
end
```